# Different effects of ORDER BY clause on two servers

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY id;
```

`id` field is a primary key, of course;

In 9.4.4 I get expected error:

```
column "table.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

BUT! In 9.4.5 it works, like in MySQL.

Can anybody tell me - why? :)

Comment: Seeing that this is a misunderstanding rather than a real issue, please delete this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres version does not matter here. The tables are not identical. Most likely in your 9.4.5 table the column `id` is a primary key, while in 9.4.4 is not.

Comment: This is it, primary key was dropped =\
Thanks